# JPQL returning no results eventhough there is data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

In my spring JPA with H2 DB currently returning no values eventhough there are values in the DB.

My DB has values:

```
INSERT INTO public.ToDo values (1, 'Java', 'completed');
INSERT INTO public.ToDo values (2, '.NET', 'pending');
INSERT INTO public.ToDo values (3, 'Word', 'completed');
INSERT INTO public.ToDo values (4, 'PPT', 'pending');
```

The DAO method for accessing the values with status(3rd row) is as below:

```
    public List<ToDo> getItemsWithStatus(String status) {
    TypedQuery<ToDo> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM ToDo u WHERE u.status LIKE :someSymbol ORDER BY 
    u.id", ToDo.class);
    query.setParameter("someSymbol", "%status%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The ToDo entity code is as below:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ToDo{
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private String status;

//getters and setters
```

}

Please find the below image for showing the debug image which is getting the status value as 'completed'
[image: Debug]

Appreciated!!!

Comment: You never use the `status` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for "status" not for the value held by the variable status. Your setParameter call should be

```
query.setParameter("someSymbol", "%" + status + "%");
```

Comment: Thanks @Eelke, that was the issue.